# MongoDB mutliple update array query (set or push) in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

In same update query we can able to update 3 different fields (1 value need to add in array and another 2 are normal fields need to updated) in MongoDB?

```
UpdateQuery.append(“$set”, new BasicDBObject().append(LAST_ACCESSED, new Date())
.append(ARRAY_HISTORY, new Date()).append(VISIT, 5));
```

Here ARRAY_HISTORY should like this
ARRAY_HISTORY [ {2015-01-01}, {2015-06-06}, {2016-03-03}]
I need to update this array along with Last_Accessed and visit.

Thanks!
Bharathi

Answer (score 0):

```
  BasicDBObject contentlastaccessdate = new BasicDBObject();
    contentlastaccessdate.put(CommonConstants.CONTENT_HISTORY_DATE, new Date());
    pushQuery.append(CommonConstants.PUSH, new BasicDBObject(ARRAY_HISTORY, contentlastaccessdate));
```

Above push comment, will helps